# How can I load remote data in Javascript and THEN process it?

Tags: javascript, json, nonblocking

I am a novice developer working on a prototype. I discovered [this sample on Codepen for Swipeable Stacked Cards](https://codepen.io/bmarcelino/pen/pLzYjE) and I'm trying to customize it to load remote JSON data.

The Codepen has a 700+ line JS function called `stackedCards()` that runs using `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded")`, which (TBH) I don't totally understand. I looked up the [MDN page on DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) but it doesn't explain what I'm missing.

I know that JS is non-blocking so I tried using different techniques but nothing worked:

- sequential function calls
- nested function calls: calling the stackedCards() function onSuccess in the fetch() call
- async/await functions

Here's the latest attempt:

```
const addItemCard = (item) => {
  var itemList = document.getElementById("content");
  //itemList.innerText = "TEST"
  console.log("Radar 4: " + item.title);
  
  var itemCard = '' +
    '        <div class="card">' +
    '          <div class="card-content">' +
    '            <div class="card-image">' +
    '              <img src="' + 'https://via.placeholder.com/100' + '" width="100%" height="100%"/>' +
    '            </div>' +
    '            <div class="card-titles">' +
    '              <h3>' + /* item.title */ 'Super Title' + '</h3>' +
    '              <h3>10 Destinations</h3>' +
    '            </div>' +
    '          </div>' +  
    '        </div>';
  itemList.innerHTML += itemCard;
}

const displayData = async () => {
  let sourceDataUrl = [JSON_URL];

  fetch(sourceDataUrl)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("Fetch response.json = " + JSON.stringify(data)); //OK PASS
      data.forEach(item => addItemCard(item));
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/GandalfTheWhite/ukfvwn1q/27/).

Comment: DOMContentLoaded just means "when the elements on the page have rendered"

Comment: What is the actual question here?

Comment: What kind of "doesn't work" is it doing?

Comment: You do not have anything in your fidlle with id `content`

Comment: This makes the fiddle work: `var itemList = document.querySelector(".stackedcards-container");
itemList.innerHTML += testCard;
`

Comment: @mplungjan, haha. No doubt that's part of the problem. The .container has the ID `content` in my local version. (I just put it in a fiddle for public viewing.) The JS code is meant to add a new `<div class="card">` in the Container for each Item in the data.

Comment: @hobbs, it's not loading the data before trying to format it with the `stackedCards()` function.